# getting statistics from a textarea

Tags: javascript

Getting text statistics from a textarea.

which would be better?

this one?

```
function getStats() {
  var text = textarea.value,
    stats = {};
  stats.chars = text.length;
  stats.words = text.split(/\S+/g).length - 1;
  stats.lines = text.replace(/[^\n]/g, "").length + 1;
  return stats.lines + " lines, " + stats.words + " words, " + stats.chars + " chars";
}
```

or this one?

```
function getStats() {
  var text = textarea.value,
    chars = text.length,
    words = text.split(/\S+/g).length - 1,
    lines = text.replace(/[^\n]/g, "").length + 1;
  return lines + " lines, " + words + " words, " + chars + " chars";
}
```

Comment: It doesnt matter at all in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one.

Not for any performance reasons, but you are just declaring a Javascript object when there is no need for one.

Creating an object to store your variables would only make sense if you were using it like:

```
function getStats() {
  var text = textarea.value,
    stats = {};
  stats.chars = text.length;
  stats.words = text.split(/\S+/g).length - 1;
  stats.lines = text.replace(/[^\n]/g, "").length + 1;
  return stats;
}
```